# Magento 1.9 change price on textbox change product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

I how can we change the price on product page based on a text box on the product page. Example of what I am thinking is if I have a text box on product page then my price should be base price multiplied by the value entered in the textbox. Qty box is different from the another text box and price will depend on both.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `jQuery` for the calculation based on quantity.

```
    jQuery('#qty').change(function(){
        var qty = this.value;
        var price=/***Your calculation***/
           jQuery('.price').html(price); /******Now update the HTML*******/
    });
```

Comment: It should not only work in frontend it should also work on cart page